# IPhone Set up for small to medium size business to be used by employees

Tags: iphone, enterprise

Been looking at answers related to business giving IPhone to it's employees for business usage and related problems (e.g. [Small-Business iPhone Deployment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/small-business-iphone-deployment)), it seems the simplest way is to just hand them the phone to be set up by the user themselves.

The only problem would be if the phone becomes connected to personal apple id rather than an apple id of the enterprise owning the phone then there might be problems when the phone is being retested and passed on to the next employee. Or is this completely false?

Sorry I am a windows user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using an MDM solution for managing the enterprise devices.

If you simply hand out devices to users to set them up themselves, and they log in with their Apple ID, the devices remains associated with their Apple ID unless the user explicitly removes it or log out of it.

This may be cumbersome and difficult to manage. Using an MDM solution to centrally manage and pre-configure the devices for employees would be the recommended approach. The MDM solution also makes it possible and easy to manage usage policies. It would also make it easy to pass around the device to a different employee.